# Unable to parse the variable within a function

Tags: parsing, var

I'm using Jay Salvats vegas plugin (http://vegas.jaysalvat.com) to generate a fullscreen background.

Rather than statically setting the background image src, I would like to generate 6 random images.

The img variables below are working (even if a bit inefficient); however, I can't seem to output the variable to the src.

Please help.

```
$( function() {
    var img1 = new String("/images/bg/"+Math.floor(Math.random()*101) + ".png");
    var img2 = new String("/images/bg/"+Math.floor(Math.random()*101) + ".png");
    var img3 = new String("/images/bg/"+Math.floor(Math.random()*101) + ".png");
    var img4 = new String("/images/bg/"+Math.floor(Math.random()*101) + ".png");
    var img5 = new String("/images/bg/"+Math.floor(Math.random()*101) + ".png");
    var img6 = new String("/images/bg/"+Math.floor(Math.random()*101) + ".png");


$.vegas( 'slideshow', {
    delay: 8000,
    backgrounds: [
        { src: '+img1+', fade: 4000 },
        { src: '+img2+', fade: 4000 },
        { src: '+img3+', fade: 4000 },
        { src: '+img4+', fade: 4000 },
        { src: '+img5+', fade: 4000 },
        { src: '+img6+', fade: 4000 }
    ]
} )( 'overlay' );

} );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why did you put the variable names in a string? It will cause the source of the image to be `+img1+` instead of the actual value of the variable.

```
$( function() {
    var img1 = new String("/images/bg/"+Math.floor(Math.random()*101) + ".png");
    var img2 = new String("/images/bg/"+Math.floor(Math.random()*101) + ".png");
    var img3 = new String("/images/bg/"+Math.floor(Math.random()*101) + ".png");
    var img4 = new String("/images/bg/"+Math.floor(Math.random()*101) + ".png");
    var img5 = new String("/images/bg/"+Math.floor(Math.random()*101) + ".png");
    var img6 = new String("/images/bg/"+Math.floor(Math.random()*101) + ".png");


$.vegas( 'slideshow', {
    delay: 8000,
    backgrounds: [
        { src: img1, fade: 4000 },
        { src: img2, fade: 4000 },
        { src: img3, fade: 4000 },
        { src: img4, fade: 4000 },
        { src: img5, fade: 4000 },
        { src: img6, fade: 4000 }
    ]
} )( 'overlay' );

} );
```

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I tried that, but I don't think it was loading the images for some reason.  I'll try it again.